# How do I run Linux on a MacBookPro(11,2) with more than one CPU?

Tags: linux, macintosh

I have a late 2013 15-inch MacBookPro (MacBookPro11,2).  I need to have Linux running on it.  The closest I have come is loading Xubuntu, which only boots with the `maxcpus=1` kernel option.

Question 1:
Is there anyway to run Xubuntu on this machine without the single CPU limit?

Alternate Question:
Is there any Linux Distribution that will boot on this machine without the single CPU limit?

Note:
Virtualization works fine, but the final goal is to dual-boot OSX and Linux.